# MySQL trigger delete passing user ID

Tags: mysql, triggers, pdo

I need to create MySQL trigger that would log user ID on delete table row statement which must fit in one query, since I'm using PHP PDO. This is what I've come up so far:

I need the way to pass user ID in the delete query even though it is irrelevant to delete action to be performed:

Normally the query would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE mytable.RowID = :rowID
```

If I could use multiple queries in my statement, I would do it like this:

```
SET @userID := :userID;
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE mytable.RowID = :rowID;
```

This way the variable @userID would be set before trigger event fires and it can use it. However since I need to squeeze my delete statement in one query, so I came up with this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE  CASE
           WHEN @userID := :userID
           THEN mytable.RowID = :rowID
           ELSE mytable.RowID IS NULL
       END
```

Just a note: RowID will never be null since it's the primary key. Now I have to create a delete trigger to log the user ID to the audit table, however I suppose that in this case trigger will be fired before the delete query itself which means that @userID variable will not be created? This was my idea of passing it as a value to the trigger.

I feel like I'm close to the solution, but this issue is a blocker. How to pass user ID value to the trigger without having multiple queries in the statement? Any thoughts, suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You can use NEW / OLD mysql trigger extensions. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Here is a sample code :

```
drop table `project`;
drop table `projectDEL`;

CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `proj_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `proj_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Proj_Type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`proj_id`)
);



CREATE TABLE `projectDEL` (
  `proj_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `proj_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Proj_Type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`proj_id`)
);


INSERT INTO `project` (`proj_id`, `proj_name`, `Proj_Type`) VALUES
(1, 'admin1', 'admin1'),
(2, 'admin2', 'admin2');


delimiter $
CREATE TRIGGER `uProjectDelete` BEFORE DELETE ON project
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

  INSERT INTO projectDEL SELECT * FROM project WHERE proj_id = OLD.proj_id;

END;$
delimiter ;

DELETE FROM project WHERE proj_id = 1;

SELECT * FROM project;
SELECT * FROM projectDEL;
```